# Using Geometry Node output as a modifier in another object, is that possible?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have created a spiral in Geometry Nodes and it is very simple, nodes included are Input, Spiral, Output, very simple and works as expected.  I would like to add a Deform/Curve modifier to another simple mesh object created in the layout.  When I attempt to add in that spiral as the Curve Object it is not available.  If I originally create the object as a spiral and then recreate the geometry, using geometry nodes, the curve object is an available object to pick from in the deform/curve but my mesh doesn't curve around the spiral.  If I do not use geometry nodes everything works fine, mesh rolls around the spiral.  So is there any way to use a curve path created using geometry nodes and subsequently use that curve object/path as a modifier for a regular mesh object?  Sorry if that is confusing but basically trying to create a carpet being rolled up correctly.  I have seen many videos of the same but they are not accurate so was trying to use geometry notes to create a realistic roll up...